# Best SFF PC GPS Programmer friendly device?

Tags: .net, gps

I'm working on a project where we will build custom SFF PCs, which will have our software on them and deploy around the world.

We would really like to have the ability for the PCs to be location aware, and we want to retrieve the current location of the PC and report it back to a central server.

It would be best if it were internal (well, maybe except for the antenna), and able to interface with .NET.

If there isn't an internal version, a USB or other external would work also.

Price is also a factor, but a smaller factor.

Ideas?

Comment: bear in mind that GPS doesn't work well, if at all, indoors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Windows 7 [sensor and location platform](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/sensors/default.mspx) which supports GPS? I understand (but have not verified) that the GPS that is packaged with the latest version of [Streets and Trips](http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2010/01/23/The-Win7-Sensor-and-Location-API_3A00_-Introduction-to-Working-with-Location-in-.NET-4-Beta-2.aspx) is fully supported by this interface.